Is there a way to suppress all warnings in an Matlab MLS script?
I have an MLX script in which I am analyzing code written by someone else. I am using this so that I have access to LaTeX snippets as well as the MatLab environment. But, I am also including incomplete code fragments as part of the document (so I can point out what I am talking about and remind myself of details). And this causes MatLab to generate error notation, which I find distracting.
I have included %#ok<*DEFNU,*NASGU,*SOFOC,*VUNUS,*NOPRT> at the top of the file to avoid much of this. But, I keep finding more errors pop up. I have tried #<*ALL> but this does not work.
Is there any way, inside the file, to suppress all errors?
Disclaimer: This question is asked in all honesty in the context that it is something that I would like an answer to so as to improve my experience of MatLab and increase my options for using it. And with the principle that since this was of interest to me, in the course of my work, then it might be of interest to others. I have attempted to explain my motivation. If this is not clear, please just ask.

So it's not code warnings you want to suppress, but editor MLint warnings with the orange underlining and associated tooltips? You can do this with a setting

@Wolfie - thanks, and you are correct - I want to suppress the warnings in the editor. Your suggestion was interesting as I was unaware of the setting panel you mention. However, that would (I believe) turn the warnings off for all files (being an editor not a file setting) but I want the equivalent of #ok<*all> in the file so I can turn it off in all edit sessions for that one file via a command in that file. Is there such an option?
